exit status of if statement in bash when condition is false
If I run help if in bash then it tells me that the exit status is "the status of the last command executed".  Let's try it:
if false; then
  echo we never get here
fi
echo $?

The last command executed above is clearly false and yet the if returns true.  What gives?

The "last command" here is the if block itself. From the POSIX standard: "The exit status of the if command shall be the exit status of the then or else compound-list that was executed, or zero, if none was executed."

Okay, so if I want the semantics that I thought it had, I'd need to capture the exit status explicitly using an else clause?  Something like if false; then echo impossible; else exit_status=$?; fi?  Or is there an easier way?

Depending on what you would like if the then branch fails, false && echo … could suffice. Otherwise try … else false; ….

The && construct can be tricky if you chain it with || but still useful at times: false && { echo we never get here; }; echo "$?"

Thank you to all 3 of you :)  Indeed, for the simple example I posted, a full if is overkill and && is enough.  I did not realize that at first but now it's obvious.  My real use case is a bit trickier and I'll explain that in the next comment.

My real use case is this: I have a function which runs grep in a loop.  Each iteration of the loop greps a different file.  The loop iterates at least once and at most twice.  I want the function to return successfully if at least one file matches the search string.

Now that I think of it, maybe I should just pass the full list of files to grep.  I was a bit reluctant to do that because grep changes the output format based on whether there is more than one file or not.  But come to think of it, there's a command line flag to control that.  And even without the flag I'm not trying to parse the output at the moment.  Hm... The return codes would be a bit different in the case of I/O error but I guess I'm not too worried about that.

Actually wait, the && idea still works even with my overcomplicated for loop

Alternatively, you could do a else; false. If the then branch is not taken, the else part would now set exit status 1.

clever, and maybe worth it, but a little annoying because it loses the original exit status... for instance grep exits with 1 when no match but 2 on error

"I want the function to return successfully if at least one file matches the search string." grep ... || grep ... does that if you don't need to run the second grep  at all when the first one succeeds.

Oh, that's clever... a bit awkward for my purposes since the I'd have to type the filename twice but still neat

You should ask a new question with a [mcve] as the best solution for the problem you're describing in comments may not involve calling grep at all.

pretty sure I need grep ... I have a string (provided by user) and want to get all lines that contain that string
